# Sequelize migrate table creation into an empty database with associations not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have created models using Sequelize CLI on my Node app (working with MySQL dialect), but I have problems doing `db:migrate` when the database is empty (without tables).

Let's say I have a 3 models:

1. `User`
2. `Task`
3. `TaskType`

**Associations:**

1. `Task` has foreign key to `User` -> `User.Id`
2. `Task` has foreign key
   to `TaskType` -> `TaskType.Id`

When my database is empty of tables, I'm doing a `sequelize db:migrate` but it fails because it says it cannot create `Task` table because it has a foreign key to `TaskType` which hasn't been created yet.

How can I solve this issue? Can I choose the order of which the tables are being created somehow or define dependencies?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you use https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto ?

Comment: Nope, never heard of it until now :)
What's the benefit? Should it be used instead of the regular sequelize-cli?

Comment: It will generate the models automatically from your database Tables

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with sequelize but I guess the way to do it is to create multiple migrations. Migrations are executed in the order of their names. For more information about doing associations you can read [this article](https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-define-sequelize-associations-using-migrations-de4333bf75a7).